# Is it possible to have permanent variables in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, environment-variables

Ok so I was trying to make a script that would only activate if it was a week after installing and first running it.

My first thought was to make a new environment variable with the activation time, and making the program check if the current time is larger than that, but I found that using `os.environ['activation-Time'] = str(time.time() + 604800)` does not actually add a new environment variable that can be accessed at a later time.

Is it possible to have a variable that gets saved each time you run the code? Or is it possible to create a new environment variable from within a python script?

Comment: Save it in a file

Comment: saving it in a file is the answer to accept really ^^

Comment: Maybe you can save the result from Python script to environment variable? `MY_ENV_VARIABLE=$(python my_script.py)`

Comment: FWIW, `activation-Time` seems to be an invalid env var name. Bash for example won't export it: ``bash: export: `activation-Time': not a valid identifier``. In any case, putting a hyphen in an env var name is probably bad practice, and so is camelCase. You could use something like `MY_SCRIPT_ACTIVATION_TIME` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of a couple ways to do this, depending on your specific needs.

1. You can use the `python-crontab` package to manage cron jobs on your system. I don't know if you are on Windows, Mac OS X, or linux, and don't know if this works on windows. But on a mac or linux, this allows you to set jobs to run on a schedule, and you could decide when you want this script to be run again.
2. You could write the last (or first?) run-time to a sqlite database, and have a cron job check that at regular intervals, and decide when to run again based on whatever logic you want.
3. I will say that environment variables are probably not the way to go, unless you write them into your shell `.rc` file, so that they are re-used by every shell you open. You still need something to try to run your script at a certain time, either manually or via a cron job.

Hope that helps, happy coding!